# workaround: make mysql column name longer than 64 chars

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I am working on an application to dynamically generate mysql tables from Excel files.

Current I am stuck because some of the column names in the Excel files have more than 64 characters, while in mysql the maximum length for column names are 64 characters.

I thought about setting up another table to store the column names but then I will have to perform some joint operation to retrieve them.

Is there any clever way to workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is an open source project. You can [download the source code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/source-installation.html), change things, and build your own version.

I haven't read MySQL source, but the odds are good that the maximum length of identifiers is a compile-time constant. It might be as simple as finding that constant, changing it, and recompiling. (*Simple* doesn't necessarily mean *easy*, though.)

It really *is* pretty easy in PostgreSQL. [The PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) even tell you the name of the constant, and which file it's in. (NAMEDATALEN, in src/include/pg_config_manual.h)

Personally, I think you're better off fixing the Excel column names to conform to MySQL limits.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to increase the length of the column size more than 64. here are some standards. you cant go beyond this limit.

```
Identifier                Maximum Length (characters)
Database                  64
Table                     64
Column                    64
Index                     64
Constraint                64
Stored Program            64
View                      64
Alias                     256
Compound Statement Label  16
```

And you cant retrive the column names through join operation. through join operation you can only achieve data of 2 or more tables. the solutio to your problem is that you should truncate the column names in excel already before exporting them to mysql.